# Joining fields from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables :

```
table 'g'
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|   32 |
|    3 |
|    6 |
|    5 |
|   22 |
|   54 |
|   21 |
+------+

table 'h'
+------+------+
| id   | sl   |
+------+------+
|    1 |  323 |
|   11 |  423 |
|    1 |  333 |
|   33 |   32 |
|   44 |  443 |
+------+------+
```

How can I show records from 2 tables like (select distinct id from 'g' and 'h' table and joining maximum 'sl' from 'h' table for each id. the 'id's of 'g' table which does not match with 'id' of table 'h', those 'sl' fields will be null)

```
+------+------+
| id   | sl   |
+------+------+
|    1 |  333 |
|   32 | null |
|    3 | null |
|    6 | null |
|    5 | null |
|   22 | null |
|   54 | null |
|   21 | null |
|   11 |  423 |
|   33 |   32 |
|   44 |  443 |
+------+------+
```

-Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a `UNION` between the two, left joined as a derived table against the `h` to get the `MAX()` values:

```
SELECT
  allids.id,
  MAX(sl) AS sl
FROM
  /* Subquery gets UNION (distinct, not UNION ALL) of ids from both tables */
  (SELECT id FROM g UNION SELECT id FROM h) allids
  /* LEFT JOINed back against `h` for the MAX() aggregates */
  LEFT JOIN h ON allids.id = h.id
GROUP BY id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c348/3

#### Update after comments:

To force them to sort in the arbitrary (un-ordered) order that they were inserted, it may sort of work to place a number literal into the subquery which gets used in the `ORDER BY`.

The order rows are inserted isn't really meaningful to the RDBMS though. You cannot reliably assume that they would always be given back to you in the same order, absent an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT
  allids.id,
  MAX(sl) AS sl
FROM
  /* Awful hack adds a number literal which is used in the ORDER BY */
  /* This still won't guarantee that the rows from each table will be in the original order though */
  (SELECT id, 1 AS sort FROM g UNION SELECT id, 2 AS sort FROM h) allids
  LEFT JOIN h ON allids.id = h.id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sort
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c348/6

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im It took me a while to find it, but the Text to DDL button makes very short work of copy/pasting table samples from SO into CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

Comment: that worked, but the id are arranged in ascending order. if I want to set id with no order and want the ids to be shown like 'g' table id first then 'h' table id with no order(as shown on my question),then what should I do ?

Comment: In fact, I had been in the process of building a tool in JS to do exactly that when I finally realized sqlfiddle _already had it_.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski "Text to DDL" button really helps. Just tried.

Comment: @user1844626 You cannot force them to be in _no particular order_. The order they are inserted in the database isn't meaningful to the RDBMS.  I added a hack above which almost gets the original order...

Comment: @michaelberkowski  glad you found my little tool handy. Funny that you were working on your own version. Btw, if you'd like to take a look at that code in isolation (and maybe contribute :) I've broken off a separate github project for it, here: https://github.com/jakefeasel/DDLBuilder (ignore the build failure message, it's fine, really)

Comment: @JakeFeasel Great to meet you, and thanks for your work! I'm excited to dig into the code a bit.